# In Blender 3.3.x Image Editor in Mask mode, Add Circle and Add Square options are greyed out. How do we activate them?

Tags: uv-image-editor, masking

In the Image Editor, I have an image loaded but when I try to create a mask, the Add Circle and Add Square options are greyed out.
I created a new Mask but the options remain unavailable and I noticed that a Mask Layer was not automatically created like in previous versions, so I created a new Mask Layer but still, the Add options are unavailable.

I have tried loading images from disk, render results both saved and unsaved, and newly created images both saved and unsaved. All cases yielding the same result.

How do I make the Mask-related Add shape buttons available in the Image Editor in Blender 3.3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in v3.3.x and has been fixed in v3.4.0.